# MUI: how to show tooltip component over selected text?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Like on medium:
[image]

Tooltip from matetial-ui react framework.

some ideas:

- wrap selected text with `<span>` and use that element as reference node
  of tooltip (over complicated I guess)
- create tooltip w/o child and specify
  absolute position based on selected text

any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp

The more effective: https://chrisbracco.com/a-simple-css-tooltip/

:)

Answer (score 0):

Medium.com uses popper.js. I found this out by searching the tag parameters in Medium's HTML.

```html
<div class="bz fx mc yw"
     style=
"position: absolute; inset: auto auto 0px 0px; transform: translate(692px, 1233px);"
     data-popper-reference-hidden="false"
     data-popper-escaped="false"
     data-popper-placement="top">
```

https://popper.js.org/

It does the thing where it repositons the popup if you scroll, I checked.

Answer (score -1):

I used the popper component instead of tooltip component link: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-popper/#virtual-element

demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/iztu66?file=/demo.js

code

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Popper from '@mui/material/Popper';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Fade from '@mui/material/Fade';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';

export default function VirtualElementPopper() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const handleMouseUp = () => {
    const selection = window.getSelection();

    // Resets when the selection has a length of 0
    if (!selection || selection.anchorOffset === selection.focusOffset) {
      handleClose();
      return;
    }

    const getBoundingClientRect = () =>
      selection.getRangeAt(0).getBoundingClientRect();

    setOpen(true);
    setAnchorEl({
      getBoundingClientRect,
    });
  };

  const id = open ? 'virtual-element-popper' : undefined;

  return (
    <div onMouseLeave={handleClose}>
      <Typography aria-describedby={id} onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ipsum purus,
        bibendum sit amet vulputate eget, porta semper ligula. Donec bibendum
        vulputate erat, ac fringilla mi finibus nec. Donec ac dolor sed dolor
        porttitor blandit vel vel purus. Fusce vel malesuada ligula. Nam quis
        vehicula ante, eu finibus est. Proin ullamcorper fermentum orci, quis finibus
        massa. Nunc lobortis, massa ut rutrum ultrices, metus metus finibus ex, sit
        amet facilisis neque enim sed neque. Quisque accumsan metus vel maximus
        consequat. Suspendisse lacinia tellus a libero volutpat maximus.
      </Typography>
      <Popper
        id={id}
        open={open}
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        transition
        placement="bottom-start"
      >
        {({ TransitionProps }) => (
          <Fade {...TransitionProps} timeout={350}>
            <Paper>
              <Typography sx={{ p: 2 }}>The content of the Popper.</Typography>
            </Paper>
          </Fade>
        )}
      </Popper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can add your own buttons after fade component or inside in paper component.

Comment: Boruzs: Your answer could use a little more detail, such as why and where you should use the component.  Thanks

Comment: If you think that this is solved just by the link, then this is a link-only answer. which is not considered to be an answer. If you think that the solution is to use the library/tool, then it is not considered an answer if you do not demonstrate how that can be used to solve the problem.